# How to set the "Read More" link (in Rewrite Rules for Body field) to point to the node url instead of the title?

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I have created the blog as a view in Drupal 7.14 site. On my main blog page, I want to show 5 trimmed versions of the posts. I have added the following fields for the main blog page view - Title, Author, Post date, Body. In the Body field, I select the following options in "Rewrite Rules" section - Trim field, add read more text. Btw, I have selected the default format for the body. I add the "More link path" as [title] after referring to the Replacement Patterns.

[image: Rewrite Rules modal window]
When I apply the changes, I see that the "Read More" links to the actual title and not the url that is linked to the title. Example, it will create a link "www.mysite.com/My post title" instead of "www.mysite.com/blog/my-post-title".

In the Title field, I have selected the option to link the field to original piece of content. 
[image: Title field settings]

The same setup worked on my localhost and it is not working on my Joyent server. Am I missing something? I have spent several hours looking at concepts like Pathauto, replacement tokens, etc, but no help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change the More link path to the **node/[nid]**

Add field nid to the views field and exclude from display. Make sure nid is above body field. Re-arrange the fields by clicking on select list next to field label and drag nid field to top of body field. It works !

Drupal l function while generating links will convert automatically to path alias blog/blog-title !

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added a field for [nid] and then tried adding [nid] and also node/[nid] as you suggested. It just blindly appends this to the site url. So, I end up getting a url "www.mysite.com/node/[nid]. Also, I noticed it does not get added to the replacement patterns.

Comment: Small changes need to be done ! Check updated answer ! Make sure nid is above body field. It works !

Answer (score 6):

You can also add a separate 'Content:Link' field:

[image: Adding the content:link field]

Then select the text you want to display on the 'Readmore' link (you may select a fixed text, or a dynamic text [like nodetitle] when you rewrite the field results).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - my assumption was the same as the OP's in that the "title" field/token would link, but it didn't, even when it was set to link to the original piece of content. I also tried the "link" field which also didn't work (same effects as reported above). It turns out the field you need is "path" - this has to be positioned above the body field (or whichever field it is you want to rewrite as the link to the node) in the fields list, and excluded.