# Summary/Trimmed field in view doesn't include Read More link

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a view, and the key display points are:

- Format: Unformatted List (I'm adjusting the views look through CSS)
- Show: Fields

One of the fields to show is Body (so, a textarea.) When I choose to display it as "Summary or Trimmed", and set the trim length to, say, 600, it trims it fine, but it doesn't show a "Read More" link to the content's page. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This may helps you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44791/how-to-set-the-read-more-link-in-rewrite-rules-for-body-field-to-point-to-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check " Add a read-more link if output is trimmed. "?

If yes, maybe the problem is, that the text is not trimmed. If you want to have a "read more" link in any case, then you sould add the field "Link" to the view. You can then also enter your custom text, e.g. "details..." instead of "read more" etc.

Comment: The problem is I'm not seeing that option; I've got "create a lable", "exclude from display" and "Formatter". If I choose "Trimmed" or "Summary or Trimmed" from "Formatter", the "Trim Length" field appears... but that's my only new option.

Comment: Nevermind. Found it. It wasn't where I was expecting. It was under "Rewrite Results". Thank you!